# python click: reuse click options from group in command

Tags: python, click

I have the following:

```py
@click.option("--option1")
@click.option("--option2")
@click.option("--option3")
@click.group()
def group(option1, option2, option3):
  pass

@click.option("--option1")
@click.option("--option2")
@click.option("--option3")
@group.command()
def cli(option1, option2, option3):
  # do something with args
  ...
```

Is there a way to reuse options between the group and the command?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following that I haven't seen done elsewhere:

```py
@click.option("--option1", default=1)
@click.option("--option2", default=2)
@click.option("--option3", default=3)
@click.group()
def group(**_):
  pass

@click.pass_context
@group.command()
def cli(ctx):
  params = ctx.parent.params
  print(params)  # {"option1": 1, "option2": 2, "option3": 3}
```

As shown above, I get the `params` from the parent context which contains key-value pairs with option name and its value.